# Sending emails through mandrill not showing up images

Tags: node.js, email, mandrill, nodemailer

I am using Mandrill (Nodemailer) through my node js application to send emails. When i am sending emails the images are not showing up. The images are `base64` encoded.

Here is my code:

```
var transport = nodemailer.createTransport(mandrillTransport({
      auth: {
        apiKey: 'mykey'
      }
    }));

transport.sendMail({  
        from: 'from@gmail.com',
        to: 'me@gmail.com',
        cc: '',
        bcc: '',
        subject: 'Email with Images',
        html: '<img src="cid:logocid">',
        images: [{
                'type': "image/png",
                'name': 'logocid',
                'content': 'R0lGODdhCgAKAHcAACH5BAUAAAEALAAAAAAKAAoAgGNlYwAAAAIRRB6Gq9edEHxM1mVz1FPvUAAAOw=='
        }]

    }, function(error, response){ 
       if(error){
           console.log(error);
       }else{
           console.log("Message sent: " + response.message);
       }

       transport.close();
    });
```

Here is my `base64` image that i want to show in email:
    `data:image/gif;base64,R0lGODdhCgAKAHcAACH5BAUAAAEALAAAAAAKAAoAgGNlYwAAAAIRRB6Gq9edEHxM1mVz1FPvUAAAOw==`

Comment: What does the source of the email you receive look like? Does it contain the image or is it missing from the email entirely? Also, in your code sample, you use 'image/png' as the mime type, but  in your comment it's image/gif.

Comment: @terrorbox : Even after changing the MIME type it doesn't work. Nope it doesn't show image at all, entirely missing.

Comment: it looks like the Mandrill transport doesn't support attachments/images directly: https://github.com/Rebelmail/nodemailer-mandrill-transport/issues/26